# Database occasionally locked while trying to open in other class

Tags: android, sqlite

Problem: db not opens occasionally on rare devices.

I have one background service.class and some UI classes. Both opens db:

```
 String ppp1=getDatabasePath("myproject.db").getAbsolutePath();
 db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(ppp1, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
```

and the service makes queries and updates **in a loop (thread)**, for example:

```
    Cursor c1;
    String q1 = "select uid from logs where type!=2";
    c1 = db.rawQuery(q1, null);
    allLogsCount += c1.getCount();
    c1.close();
```

And **problem**: sometimes UI class at onCreate() can not open db, errors are differnt:

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: Failed to change locale for db /data/data/com.myproject.android/databases/myproject.db to en_US .
```

or

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: attempt to re-open an already-closed object: SQLiteDatabase: /data/user/0/com.myproject.android/databases/myproject.db
```

or just

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabaseLockedException: database is locked (code 5)
```

service runs NOT in separate process. No unclosed cursors, I checked it. and it happens only on one device - Panasonic ToughPad FZ-X1 (SDK 17)

what I am doing wrong?

Comment: In your service class after you are closing cursor are you closing database also like this **db.close();**

Comment: Are you using a `SQLiteOpenHelper`?

Comment: Karakuri, not. L-X, not.  Hey you, I open it in onCreate() in main thread of class, and close it in onDestroy()